# Ubuntu shows only console login after I start my computer

Tags: login, console

Ubuntu shows only login console but no gui login. Even though I entered right login user name and password, I can't login. I can't do anything with this. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You seem to have two (likely) unrelated problems here: 1) Not being able to log in and 2) the absence of a graphical user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the server version was installed on your box. You should install desktop environment by running one of these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop #GNOME
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop #KDE
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop #xfce
```

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is for unity

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from user528561 does not work (or even before this) try pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7. Note thet if you have laptop the F7 key may have some other function atached to it and you must press the Fn key also. Once I pressed Ctrl + Alt + F1 by acctident and was moved to console...In most cases the F7 key is GUI, but sometimes can be F8. Sorry for bad writing and no edditing, I am in a hurry.

Comment: Neither works. First I had to login before I install any packages. I can't even login with correct credentials,